# Is there a way to make a formula to read cells that contain numbers and letters?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I want to make a way to where I can type a ID that contains letter and number for example (824CCTF5eb4f), and that it will display me some other information that I want...

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("qwerty1234567890asdfghjkl0987654321";"Alumnos Mundial!A2:E7"); "SELECT * WHERE Col1 LIKE '"&MAYUSC(G2)&"' OR Col2 LIKE '"&MAYUSC(G2)&"'")

With this formula I can get only cells that have numbers and this is my result:
[image: Example of my result:]

I try removing the MAYUSC(IN ENGLISH IS UPPERC), but nothing happens and try changing it to different functions but no result; Thanks

Comment: try to replace Col1 and Col2 with upper(Col1) and upper(Col2)

Comment: The question describes the variable (`824CCTF5eb4f` ) but it does not include any data so users can't identify the relationship between the variable and the actual data.  In short, whether `LIKE`, `UPPER`, or just plain `=` are appropriate is speculation. Would you please edit the question to include some sample data, and an example of a successful outcome (based on the sample data).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the like function, you will want to include the % wildcard.

```
=query(your_range, "select * where Col1 like '%"&lookup_value&"%'")
```

The % at the start is 'ends with', % at the end is 'starts with', and at both start and end 'contains'.